# Out of memory - Graphics.DrawImage

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I got some code that retrieves an image from the database, then re sizes it for display purposes on certain pages.
However I get an "Out of memory" error on certain images.

In my current case, I only get it on one image, rest of the images work fine.

Please see my code below. Am I missing something? Am I not releasing objects correctly? Or some of my using statements are should be improved? 
The canvas.DrawImage line give the error.
Any help in locating errors in my code would be greatly appreciated.

Platform build is: Any CPU
My OS: Win 7 64bit

```
private byte[] SaveResizedImage(byte[] origImageBytes, int targetSize)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(origImageBytes))
    using (Image origImage = Image.FromStream(ms))
    {
        Size newSize = CalculateDimensions(origImage.Size, targetSize);

        using (Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newSize.Width, newSize.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
        using (Graphics canvas = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            canvas.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            canvas.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            canvas.DrawImage(origImage, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), newSize)); <--- This line give the exception error

            ImageCodecInfo codecInfo = GetEncoderInfo(ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
            encoderParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 75L);

            using (MemoryStream newms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                newImage.Save(newms, codecInfo, encoderParams);
                return newms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(ImageFormat format)
{
    return ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().ToList().Find(delegate(ImageCodecInfo codec)
        {
            return codec.FormatID == format.Guid;
        });
}

private static Size CalculateDimensions(Size oldSize, int targetSize)
{
    Size newSize = new Size();
    if (oldSize.Height > oldSize.Width)
    {
        newSize.Width = (int)(oldSize.Width * ((float)targetSize / (float)oldSize.Height));
        newSize.Height = targetSize;
    }
    else
    {
        newSize.Width = targetSize;
        newSize.Height = (int)(oldSize.Height * ((float)targetSize / (float)oldSize.Width));
    }
    return newSize;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The GDI is known to throw false OOM during conversions. Your problem could be a corrupt BMP file or an unsupported format. Or ...

Comment: How big is the image, i.e. what are the values of targetSize and origImage.Size? Are you running on 32 bit or 64 bit? Read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx

Comment: @KrisVandermotten That article is not anyway related to this question. This is gdi+ issue.

Comment: The typical reason for OOM is ... that there is indeed not enough memory. What are the sizes of the images, and what is the `targetSize`?

Comment: The original image size is 2974366 (2.9mb, 3264x2448), the target size is 3856 (120x95).
So the image in sql is pretty large compared to all the others (50-300kb). Everything works fine local, but not on the hosted server, this one image does not load and gives the error.

Comment: I added a check, that if the file size is more than 2mb, to skip the resizing/compression method above. Then it works fine, just a slow loading image. I feel this is just a quick "fix" though and know something must be wrong with my code. Any idea on perhaps my code not releasing or disposing correctly? Don;t want their server to build up memory usage and giving other out of memory issues :(

Comment: Seems that you're using `using` properly ;) Note that the image 3264x2448 takes around 30mb assuming 32bpp. I saw in some SO questions that sometimes changing the format helps to get around some GDI+ limitations. I doubt they're 30mb per image though.

Comment: Thanks @BartoszKP! Yeah, the main issue is the size of the image, one shouldn't work with such big jpg files anyway, it just puts unnecessary loading on the website. Any idea on the format change required to prevent the bug? Still in the dark about this.

Comment: Sorry, can't seem to find this question again. Someone just put all possible formats in a loop and tried to invoke `Save` for a large image. Some formats threw the exception, and some didn't. Maybe you could try this also, and find the one that won't crash.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while treating multiple images in loops. I solved it this way:
- I made sure that images, bitmaps objects etc. are disposed whenever they aren't needed anymore.
- I added GC.Collect() at the start of the method where the exeception was thrown.

It looks like, in general, when you deal with graphics, you better explicitely call the garbage collector sometimes.

Now, it possible that your computer actually lacks memory, but this may help pushing the treatment further.